# How can I download/upload only more recent files to S3 with boto3?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I'm struggling to find how to only copy some potentially huge files if the destination version is older or doesn't exist. I'm wanting something similar to AWS CLI sync function but it seems this does not exist in boto3.

I'm trying to implement something that looks at the timestamp of the files using

```
fileObj.get('LastModified')
```

where the fileObj is taken from a paginator result. However in an experiment where I use

```
self.s3Client.upload_fileobj(data, bucket_name, destpath)
```

to upload a file followed by

```
self.s3Client.download_file(bucket_name, key, localPath)
```

to download it again, I find the LastModified date has been changed each time both on the upload and on the download. This seems to make my approach impossible.

Has anybody worked out a solution to this? It would be great to see a code snippet.